# How to group by over related model count in Django ORM

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm, django-aggregation

Let's say I have the following models:

```
class Conversation(Model):
  ...

class Message(Model):
  conversation = models.ForeignKey(Conversation)
```

The following code counts the number of messages for each conversation:

```
Conversation.objects \
            .filter(...) \
            .annotate(size=Count("message")) \
            .values("size")
```

and returns a query set of `{'size': 0}, {'size': 1}, {'size': 0}, {'size': 0}` etc.

But how do I aggregate over the conversation sizes? That is, obtaining a result something like this: `(0, 3), (1, 1)`, where the first element in each pair is the conversation size and the second element is the number of conversations of this size?

Comment: Probably you can do that only through python after running the query.

Comment: Probably have to write some custom SQL.